# How can i set maximum number of steps on y axis in live charts?

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I have just started exploring the live chart library however can't seem to get the Y axis to fix number of steps. Min and Max Value of Y axis keeps on changing on my chart which shows speed on y axis.

How can i fix maximum number of steps on y axis?

I appreciate any help on this one!

Answer (score 0):

I think the separator property of the axis is what you are looking for.

[Seperator Class Definition](https://lvcharts.net/App/documentation/beta/wf/LiveCharts-Wpf-Separator)

After you defined the Step property of the separator,  you need to define the maxValue for your Y Axis in relation to the amount of steps you want to see.

[Axis Class Definiton](https://lvcharts.net/App/documentation/beta/wf/LiveCharts-Wpf-Axis)

Comment: thanks for the response. i know about the separator class i have set the step but my maxvalue for y axis  is not fixed it changes after every 5 seconds, i want to fix number of steps as 10 without fixing the maximum value

Comment: The maximum of an axis and the count of steps are connected. You cannot define the count of separators. If you want to have the same count of seperators, you need to change the value of the seperator when the maximum value is changing.

Comment: Even of i change the max value, how can i show the count of separators as 10. Could you provide an example?

Comment: i somehow managed to set the number of steps based on my max value , now the issue is my last max value is not shown on graph and also the separator lines doesnt show for some values.

Comment: please go through https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/issues/617 as i cant paste the snapshot here.